# Getting previous data on array push

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

i have an array to be mapped to an array to show in graph, the array values change when we change the date, But for me the new value is added with the previous value,

```
let salesToday_result = self.graphPlotting(res.today);
salesToday_result[0].map(item =>{self.salesChartLabels.push(moment(moment.utc(item).toDate()).format("hh A"))})
self.salesChartData[0]['data'] = salesToday_result[1];
console.log('self.salesChartLabels',self.salesChartLabels)
```

As you can see in the image below,

24hr Data is added every time i change the date

[image]

[image]

[image]

How it can be solved,(if more code needed,can be provided)

Comment: More code is needed because we don't know your model. Please provide a [mcve] so that we don't have to deal with your business logic, and only the technical part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing onto the array `self.salesChartLabels` you need to clear the array before you start pushing into, if you want to reset the labels.

**If you want to completely reset the labels and graphPlotting in synchronous**, you can try this:

```
let salesToday_result = self.graphPlotting(res.today);
self.salesChartLabels = [];
salesToday_result[0].map(item =>{self.salesChartLabels.push(moment(moment.utc(item).toDate()).format("hh A"))})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using map, maybe what you want is to do as follows:

```
let salesToday_result = self.graphPlotting(res.today);
self.salesChartLabels = salesToday_result[0].map(item => moment(moment.utc(item).toDate()).format("hh A"));
```